# I can not find ubuntu mini

Tags: 17.10

Where did ubuntu mini go? Did it change names or was it discontinued? Is there an equivelent?

I just came from 14.04 and want to get current 17.10 but i need mini. Or is there an equivelent?

I searched the ubuntu web site. But i did not see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the netboot images, they can be found [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/).

Some more information can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

In either case you can select which software you want to install.

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you. The name has been changed since I last did a network install of Ubuntu.  It is for a hotel. (I can not say which one) but we all thank you.

Comment: You can't really have tried: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads lists it...